# Coq: can I use a type argument as the type of successive argument?

Tags: coq, typing, parametric-polymorphism, adhoc-polymorphism

Simply, can I write

```
Inductive witness : (X : Type) -> X -> Type :=
  | witness_nat : witness nat 1. (* for example *)
```

such that `X` is an argument, rather than a parameter, so I can have the constructors do ad-hoc polymorphism with `X`?

## Context

I'm trying to encode a typing judgement, and I'd like it to be polymorphic, because I have lots of typing rules for different kinds of terms (Coq types) but all the rules have the same judgement form.

That means, for Coq types `A`, `B`, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
Inductive typing_judgement : (X : Type) -> context -> X -> myType -> Prop :=
  | type_A : ... (* type terms of Coq type A *)
  | type_B_1 : ... (* type terms of Coq type B, one way *)
  | type_B_2 : ... (* type terms of type B, another way *)
```

and then be able to `inversion` in the appropriate places to (say) just match on constructors `type_B_1` and `type_B_2` if it's known that `X` is actually `B`.

#### In Haskell

I'm basically mocking up a pattern that GHC's `GADTs` allow:

```hs
data Judgement termType
  = Type_A :: ... -> Judgement A
  | Type_B_1 :: ... -> Judgement B
  | Type_B_2 :: ... -> Judgement B
```

where the compiler is smart enough to use `Type_A` as a witness to `termType ~ A` - though I don't think it can elide match arms in the same way `inversion` might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; you just need the `forall` keyword:

```
Inductive witness : forall (X : Type), X -> Type :=
  | witness_nat : witness nat 1.
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Do you happen to know why the other form doesn't work? Does the forall change the scope of `X` in some way?

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel No deep reason, I think. Though you don't need the forall on the left hand side of the colon, you need a forall to bind the argument of a dependent function. It's just the way the syntax works.